# CSS Block Ignored/Overwritten by Browser

Tags: php, html, css

So I have two style blocks:

```
._bordercols {

border-right-style: solid;
border-right: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
height: 35px !important;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-bottom: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
color: #3f8bbf !important;
}

._display_title {

text-overflow: hidden !important; 
white-space: nowrap !important; 
overflow: hidden !important;

}
```

Now I call them the following way:

```
<?php     
printf(" <div class='row entrystyle ".$css_class."'>
                                    <div class='col-sm-1 _bordercols' style='color: #397dad;'>%s</div>
                                    <div class='col-sm-1 _bordercols' style='color: #397dad;'>%s</div>
                                    <div class='col-sm-2 _bordercols'><a href='./index.php'><center>%s</a></div>
                                    <div class='col-sm-6 _bordercols _display_title'>%s</div>
                                    <div class='col-sm-2 _bordercols'><center><b>%s</b></div>
                                </div>", $row['blah1'], $row['blah2'], $row['blah3'], $row['blah4'], $row['blah5']);

                    }
?>
```

Nothing happens to the div I want to format when I do it this way. If I add this style as an inline style attribute to the div, then it works like I need it to. In the Chrome inspector it doesn't even list **_display_title** as a rendered class but it does list _bordercols.

Comment: remove the _ in front of the class and check.

Comment: @HemaNandagopal yep, I added the underscore as a last resort before posting here, just maybe if for whatever reason that class name was already reserved.

Comment: okay,Even then you are facing that issue?

Comment: Could it be because the `a` tag is a persistent little thing and you want `._display_title a` rather than just `._display_title`?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gu1pdh5a/5/ i created a jsfiddle with your code and it gets all the styles

Comment: @edisoni.1337 thanks, I'll update the post with a larger chunk of code, so you can get a better picture.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is using invalid CSS.

Comment: @Rob read my comment on the answer, please.

Comment: This is also not a PHP problem and should not include PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

You using this property wrong

`text-overflow: hidden !important;`

It should be like this

- **clip**  Default value. Clips the text
- **ellipsis**  Render an ellipsis ("...") to represent clipped text
- **string**    Render the given string to represent clipped text
- **initial**   Sets this property to its default value.
- **inherit**   Inherits this property from its parent element.

So you can use **text-overflow:** `clip or ellipsis or string or initial or inherit`.

Hope it will helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately, the entire class is not being rendered. I did fix it to 'clip' but still, the CSS render in Chrome does not show _dispay_title as one of the applied classes to the div.

Comment: @Micard To put it another way, there is no property value "hidden" for `text-overflow`.